# Can't execute web-server in AngularJS phonecat application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

I downloaded AngularJS phonecat standard app, and installed Node. But when I move to directory with code and try 'npm start' I get the following error:

```
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start /Users/marya/JS:HTML:CSS/angular-phonecat
> http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000

sh: http-server: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.17.2/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/marya/JS:HTML:CSS/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well it does seem like you haven't installed the http-server package.

Try the line below. It should work if it is included in your package.json

```
$ npm install
```

otherwise try:

```
$ npm install http-server
```

Comment: If you look at the error, it's running it with bash. It needs to be installed globally.

Comment: Ben Fortune, please, create the answer, because it works! I don't understand why; please, describe it in your anwser and I'll mark it as right answer. Thanks!

Comment: +1 @cbass, this solved my issue. I had the same error.